# Inline assembler call for subroutine

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I have question about inline assembler. It's possible to call another assembler subroutine from inline assembler within the same function? For example:

```
void FindValidPID(unsigned int &Pid) 
{
    __asm
    {
        sub esp, 20h
        mov eax, Pid
        add eax,eax
        call sub123 ; another assm subroutine
        mov Pid, eax
        add esp, 20h
    }
}
```

Where I should, and how, write subroutine sub123?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: What do you mean by the "same" function? You don't mean recursion, or defining an alternate entry point for a kind of sub-recursion. It looks like you want to simply define and call a function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing an entire subroutine in assembly, you should look into using the file-level assembler rather than inline.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a subroutine `_func2` written in assembler (I only know NASM syntax).

```
    global  _func2

    section .text
_func2:
    ret
```

You can call this subroutine from your C++ code like this

```
extern "C" {
void func2();
}

void func1()
{
    __asm {
        call func2
    }
}

int main()
{
    func1();
}
```

Of course `func2` can also be a C/C++ function with an `__asm` block.

Answer (score 1):

From the syntax, I assume the compiler being used is VC++? If so, a naked function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ekezyy2(VS.80).aspx) should let you define a function that can be easily called from assembly language code.

(Naked functions are also visible to C++, so you can call them from C++ as well and potentially get the wrong results... so you just have to be careful!)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating the other function just as you did with the 1st one and then call it with its mangled name like `call __GLOBAL__I_sub123;`.

It might be a good idea to declare it as `extern "C"` to make things simpler.

In gcc, you can use `gcc -S file.cpp` to see what is the funciton's mangled name.